# How can I create struct vfsmount from inode?

Tags: c, struct, kernel

I have a function I need to implement, which gets the `i_node` (`struct inode *`)and `d_entry` (`struct dentry *`) as input arguments. How can I create the `vfsmount` from these two inputs?

Comment: `vfsmount` denotes filesystem instance, mounted somewhere. Do you want to *return existing mount*, which given inode belongs to, or to *create new mount* at the given inode?

Comment: I want to return the existing vfsmount

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, you cannot. `vfsmount` object is accessible for `file` object, not for `dentry` one (`inode` can be viewed as strictly connected to `dentry`, so it doesn't add something new to `dentry`).

`dentry` object has no `vfsmount` object, universally corresponded to it: it depends from [mnt_namespace](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/mount.h#L7) object. You can get namespace for e.g. current process: `current->nsproxy->mnt_ns`, but you shouldn't iterate mounts in this object without taking `namespace_sem` semaphore, which is declared as static in `fs/namespace.c`.

If you want to implement some access policy, based on files, you may found this [conversation](http://lkml.iu.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/0409.0/0994.html) helpfull:

> There is no canonical full path for a given dentry.

(`path` object has a field, denoted corresponded `vfsmount` object).